# Javascript function innerText

Tags: javascript, innertext

I want to get the innerText of "lid" but when I write "lid.innerText I get null values is there any other way.

```
function zoom() {
 var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value; //value from searchbox
// console.log(input);
 d3.json("intervals.json", function(alldata)  // entering json file  to look for oid
 {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < alldata.records.length; i++)  //for loop for getting the oid  alldata.records.length;
    {

      conceptid = alldata.records[i].oid;  //saving all the oid in conceptid
      lid = ("l" + conceptid.toString());  //concatenate with "l"
      console.log(lid);

      if (document.getElementById(lid).innerText === input)  // if lid.innertext = input
      {

        document.getElementById(lid).click();  //then zoom
      }

    }

 });
}
```

Comment: `lid` is just a string.  It doesn't have innerText.

Comment: The code example doesn't use `lid.innerText`? Does `document.getElementById(lid)` match anything?

Comment: show DOM as well

Comment: Hi amruta, please can you share more info? What element does "lid" represent? Can you share the output of console.log(document.getElementById(lid)) and share output?

Comment: ```console.log(document.getElementById(lid)); ``` gives me the list of all "lid" for e.g - ```<text x="695.1503373250064" y="101.66666666666666" width="136.33184814453125" height="19.999999999999986" class="fullName level4" id="l40" style="display: none; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Early/Lower Cretaceous</text>```.                                                                                                             All I want is to fetch "Early/Lower Cretaceous" from query.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried, and got innertText correctly. Can you output what your "input" is? Maybe output console log it as well.

Comment: "input " is something that the user is going to enter (for e.g "Early/Lower Cretaceous "and the console.log(input)  will show "Early/Lower Cretaceous".

Comment: Is it possible to share .json file? Maybe some entries in it are corrupted or don't have innerText and when the for loop iterates through that entry, you get null.

Comment: I cannot share the .json file but I cross-verified it has all the entries.

Comment: In the description you've written you get null by using "lid.innerText" which obviously will give null. In the code you've used "document.getElementById(lid).innerText" which is the right way, and I've got output correctly.

Can you tell which of the above is giving you error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element is `<text>` which is a special tag inside `<svg>` so `innerText` does not apply. Use `textContent` instead:

```
  if (document.getElementById(lid).textContent === input)
```